# Why does using parameterized queries or entity framework prevent sql injection?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-injection, prepared-statement

I've got a good grasp on SQL injection. It's when a SQL query that is supposed to be something like

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName 
FROM Customers 
WHERE CustomerId = @valueFromApplication
```

Gets turned into a query like

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName 
FROM Customers 
WHERE CustomerId = '' ; DROP DATABASE Foo --
```

When the user inserts a malicious value into your app, website, client, whatever.. I'm also aware that instead of just dropping the DB the attacker can try to discover the names of tables and get info out of them.

I also know some things that help prevent this are:

1. Using stored procedures which take parameters (SQL Server)
2. Using parametrized SQL queries
3. Using Entity Framework / LINQ to Entities (C#, maybe F#?)

How do these things actually prevent SQL injection from occurring? Why can't the attacker just pass the same malicious value into whatever input he or she is already using and have the same result.

Comment: Because if something will be send as parameter, then SQL server will treat it as parameter, and won't try to treat\execute it as SQL code. So content of parameter won't be executed

Comment: Your first SQL statement is parameterized and is not vulnerable to SQL injection. The C# code `string sql = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId = " + valueFromApplication;` is vulnerable.

Comment: when you pass to parameter some code breaking syntax like '--' or ';' are treated as normal character and simply insert or update those into your column field or do other job e.g LIKE operator will search parameter value ";Drop Database.."  as string itself instead executing.

Comment: prepared statements are acutally precompiled into stored procedures for speed and security.

Comment: As a bonus, most APIs for executing a parameterised statement will only execute a single statement at a time.

Comment: @Blorgbeard thanks for the feedback. I put in a bad example there and will update it to a query that is actually vulnerable to SQL injection

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your first example is parameterised and is not vulnerable to SQL injection.

Parameterised queries aren't simply replaced by the server with values (like you might do manually replacing `@var` with `value`). They are sent and received exactly as you sent it.. with `@valueFromApplication`.

The server will parse the query.. and when it gets to a variable it will look up the value supplied. If that value is `'' ; DROP DATABASE Foo --`.. then that becomes the **value** it uses. It doesn't parse that.. it just uses it as text/number/whatever type it is.

To add about Entity Framework, it internally uses Parameterised query so it is also SQL injection safe.

Answer (score 10):

Parameters are not simply replaced in-line into the SQL - they are sent separately from the query to the SQL Server.

So, SQL Server gets something like:

```
Query:
   SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId = ?
Parameter 1:
   '' ; DROP DATABASE Foo --
```

And therefore it compiles a query that checks for a customer whose CustomerId is literally equal to `'' ; DROP DATABASE Foo --`. The parameter value is never executed as SQL.